# Testes do HTML (DOM) com Jasmine ou outro framework

Tags: jquery, testes, testes-de-unidade, jasmine

Como faço pra testar o HTML com jasmine? 
Sei que existe um cara chamado jquery-jasmine.js que faz isso mas não tenho idéia de como instalá-lo porque o npm não funciona quando eu tento instalar ele (fala que o Git pode estar com problemas, mas todos os outros plugins funcionam noormalmente ao tentar instalar).
Então, se você usa o jasmine, poderia me informar como testar HTML com ele?
Ou se você usa outro framework de testes que funcione com o DOM também, poderia me indicar?

Obrigado!

EDIT:
Eu uso AngularJS e, tendo um elemento com o atributo `ng-model="nome"` e uma label `<label id='replicaNome'>{{nome}}</label>`, eu gostaria de fazer o seguinte teste: Todo valor que estiver escrito no ng-model="nome" deve ser replicado na label, algo assim:

```
it('Teste de mudança de HTML no projeto', function () {
    document.getElementById("nome").innerHTML("Testando");
    expect(document.getElementById("teste").innerHTML).toBe("Testando");
});
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Junior, coloque aqui o que quer testar que nós ajudamos no que soubermos. Eu uso Jasmine nos testes que fazemos para o [MooTools](http://mootools.net). Aqui fica um exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Bw2tA/

Comment: Sergio editei a pergunta, obrigado!

Comment: Pode dar também um exemplo do código que quer testar? ie, uma linha de código que produz um resultado que o teste deve verificar.

Comment: Consegui fazer com Protractor, obrigado Sérgio!

Comment: Coloque aqui como resposta a conclusão a que chegou, que pode ser util a outros também.